# MySQL: Selecting rows ordered by character count

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

In MySQL, how can I order my query by character count?

Answer (score 23):

Try using the [`LENGTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length) function:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY LENGTH(myField);
```

Depending on what you're doing, you might want to use [`CHAR_LENGTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) instead:

> A multi-byte character counts as a single character. This means that for a string containing five two-byte characters, LENGTH() returns 10, whereas CHAR_LENGTH() returns 5.

If you don't know what that means, you probably want `LENGTH`.

Comment: What does ... do in MySQL? ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I edited it to just use the dreaded asterisk. :) I guess I'd rather put up an inefficient query than a non-working one.

Comment: meh, even MySQL's own documentation uses ellipsis to signify omitted code: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html . It's quite common to use "..." to represent variable parameters or omissions in programming.

Comment: Well they use it on inline text, but whenever they separate out into a code block they use table names. I feel that's probably the best way to go.

Comment: Wow, I could never have predicted that I would cause such a principled exchange, I was only having a laugh :)